# How to install Gnome 3.10 on Debian

Tags: debian, gnome3

I am using Debian Testing (Sid) and i want to install Gnome 3.10. How can i do it? Is there a repository I can add in order to upgrade? I have searched a lot and the only thing I have found is the Ubuntu repositories but I don't think that's safe.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe, Ubuntu repositories are not compatible with Debian. While they might work, it is really not a good idea to mix them.

At the moment, the newest version of gnome available in the [Debian repos](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gnome&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) is 3.8.

If you really want to try the new Gnome out, you will either have to wait until a .deb is released (keep your eye on the `experimental` and `unstable` repositories) or, if you just can't wait, you will need to compile and install it from source. The easiest way to do that would be to use JHBuild and build the package yourself. See [here](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/introduction.html.en) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow [this article](http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html)

Aptitude is an Ncurses based FrontEnd to Apt, the debian package manager.

Tasksel is a tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated “task” onto your system.

```
# apt-get install aptitude tasksel
```

Install gnome on debian

```
# tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```

Answer (score 0):

GNOME 3.10 has some parts in experimental .

For e.g. :-

```
$ apt-show-versions -a empathy
empathy:amd64 3.8.4-3 install ok installed
empathy:amd64 3.8.4-3  testing      debian.ec.as6453.net
empathy:amd64 3.8.4-3  unstable     debian.ec.as6453.net
empathy:amd64 3.10.1-2 experimental debian.ec.as6453.net
empathy:amd64/testing 3.8.4-3 uptodate
```

As can be seen empathy has 3.10 in experimental. I have added all the sources as I have and want a mixed system.

But the whole gnome 3.10  is not yet in experimental.

See http://www.0d.be/debian/debian-gnome-3.10-status.html

For a status of which packages are in testing, which ones are in unstable/sid and which ones are in experimental.

Now, there are things to understand and think about. The ones in experimental may or may not work. I wouldn't recommend running GNOME 3.10 unless you can live with a broken system.

If you think you can handle a broken Debian system, sure. Do you know for instance what to do if libpam0g breaks, preventing all logins or do you know what to do if grep breaks, causing the boot process to hang forever? These things have happened. They will happen again.

If you want to still go ahead, go ahead, the only advice I would give then is to not to either use in a production system or make debian install on another partition and use/test it there.

the rest is upto you.